# Weird Git state: rebase says there is a change in a file, status says there isn't, checkout says the file doesn't exist, ls-files says it does

Tags: git

I don't understand how I could have got to this state and how to fix it:

```
alexey@DESKTOP-41AVESA:~/project$ git rebase origin/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        bin/analyzer
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
error: could not detach HEAD

alexey@DESKTOP-41AVESA:~/project$ git status
On branch ...
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/...'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .envrc

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

alexey@DESKTOP-41AVESA:~/project$ git co HEAD bin/analyzer
error: pathspec 'bin/analyzer' did not match any file(s) known to git

alexey@DESKTOP-41AVESA:~/project$ git ls-files bin
bin/analyzer
...
```

Comment: are you ignoring changes on that file on purpose? Like `git update-index --assume-unchanged`? Sounds like it.

Comment: I actually tried `--no-assume-unchanged` before asking this question, but it turned out to be `--skip-worktree` instead.